# Is there a way to make IntelliJ IDEA show output under the editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

At the moment, IntelliJ IDEA's main screen looks like this:

```
.............................................................
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|------------------Y.........................................|
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|..................`........................................'|
|                                                            |
| Here is the output...                                      |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|............................................................'
```

I tried everything to make the output dockable like in the ASCII art below, and failed. Is there any way to make it look like:

```
..............................................................
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|------------------Y.........................................|
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  |                                        ||
|                  :........................................'|
|                  |                                         |
|                  | Here is the output...                   |
|                  |                                         |
|                  |                                         |
|                  |                                         |
|                  |                                         |
|............................................................'
```

(BTW: ASCII art was made with Jave - http://www.jave.de/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is quite simple since version 13:

**TL;DR**

`Settings` -> `Appearance` -> `Widescreen tool window layout`

---

Here's my initial layout:

[image]

Now go to `Settings` -> `Appearance` and check the box for `Widescreen tool window layout`:

[image]

And now you have the nice layout you were expecting:

[image]

Comment: Man, I almost gave up on IdeaJ - you saved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make both the project and output windows `pinned` and `docked` you should get the layout you're looking for.

Comment: They are both pinned and docked in the first "screen" I gave. So no, it does not do what I need. However, if they are both pinned and docked, and the dockable they are in is in the "split" mode, they appear together. Which I do not want.